# Exclamations that aren't appeals to a deity

Tags: word-choice

I'm looking for words or phrases that are not appeals to a deity ("oh my God"), but still show strong emotion. Please don't give phrases that are exclamations but don't show strong emotions (who says "oh (my) gosh" in a fit of rage?). I also think we can take vulgarities for granted.

Comment: If you leave out vulgarities, you got nothing left. Strong emotions are vulgar, especially when expressed in language.

Comment: Other than minced oaths, I can't think of any either

Comment: I can think of some archaic ones: *woe is me, alas, alack...*

Comment: This question has been asked before see http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/154284/how-can-i-express-strong-emotions-without-using-biblical-or-profane-language/154318#154318 and it was closed because it was too broad.

Answer (score 1):

- Son of a Biscuit
- Son of a Beach
- Darn-it
- Crap
- Mother Trucker
- Dagnabit
- Good grief (Charilie Brown)
- Dang-it
- Yo-Yo Ma (Kramer)
- Serenity Now (George Costanza)
- Poo Poo head (kindergarteners)
- Bugger (A Christmas Story)
- Oh Fudge (A Christmas Story)

That's all I can think of.  Now beat it.

Comment: I don't see any of these actually being used by someone abruptly grasped by a strong emotion though, with the possible exception of dang-it.

Comment: @KnightOfNi - It depends on your personality.  I wouldn't say many of these words.  Maybe dang-it maybe serenity now maybe crap.  I have heard most/all of these screamed the past year.  Often they might be said because they aren't allowed to say the vulgar versions (my kid's preschool teachers) or they are kids or at work and trying to be professional.

Answer (score 0):

"Oh! Bother!"

"Goodness me!"

"Good gracious!"

"What the hell...?"

"Rats!"

Comment: I'm a fan of "what the...?" No *hell*, no *heck*, just "what the...?" Like the old horror movie adage goes: what the audience imagines is always much worse than anything you could show them.

Answer (score 0):

Some people say - Well, I'll be - This leaves others to make their own conclusions.
Strike me Roan or Strike me lucky - could be construed with making appeals to a deity but then again it may not. It is sort of inconclusive.

Answer (score 0):

"Incredible"

"Unbelievable"

"I can't believe it"

I've used all of the of both in both positive and negative senses. Tone and volume convey a lot.